# Jquery Cycle - displaying more than one div

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

Just working with the Jquery Cycle plugin, and I have a box which allows users to scroll through a list of categories in boxes. But I can't seem to find a way to allow Jquery Cycle to display more than one of the boxes at a time, allowing users to scroll up or down to reveal more boxes.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="themeSearch">
    <h1 class="mainSectionHeader">By Theme</h1>
    <div class="scrollUp eventSearchScroll"><a href="#" id="prev6"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/scrollUp.png" alt="Scroll Up" /></a></div>
    <div id="themeSelector">
        <div class="themeItem"><p><span>On foot<span></p><a href="#"><span>Go</span></a></div>
        <div class="themeItem"><p><span>Vintage Coach<span></p><a href="#"><span>Go</span></a></div>
        <div class="themeItem"><p><span>Helicopter<span></p><a href="#"><span>Go</span></a></div>
        <div class="themeItem"><p><span>Boat<span></p><a href="#"><span>Go</span></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollDown eventSearchScroll"><a href="#" id="next6"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/scrollDown.png" alt="Scroll Down" /></a></div>
</div>
```

...the css:

```
    #themeSearch {
    background: url(../images/bgRed.png) top left repeat;
    width: 275px;
    height:346px;
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
#themeSelector {
    height:216px;
}
.themeItem {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid #6e060a;
    clear: both;
    margin: 19.5px 0;
}
```

...and the js:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#themeSelector').cycle({ 
    fx:     'scrollUp', 
    timeout: 6000, 
    delay:  -2000 ,
    next:   '#next6', 
    prev:   '#prev6'
});
});
```

In this particular case, I want to show about 4 'themeItems' at one time, allowing users to scroll up and down to reveal more.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds more like you need to use something like jCarousel

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery cycle can only show one 'slide' at a time, you could simulate what you're trying to do though by putting more than one item of content (for example three or four images) into a single slide. That way you'd have 3 or 4 image showing at once, and when the container cycles you'll get your next slide of 3-4 images.

Comment: Thanks @Hath.

Clive - I did actually consider this method, but unfortunately this section of the page is planned to be content manageable so it wouldn't work very well in regards to the CMS I'm using. Thanks alot though!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try:

http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/

where you can specify visbility:

`visible: 2`

To show 2 images

Answer (score 0):

it can be done.
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/div.html

Cycle Script begins with the navigation element(s) such as:

`<div style="margin:auto;text-align:center"><div id="nav"></div></div>`

and continues with the slide div:

```
`<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="images/beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="images/beach5.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="images/beach6.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/images/beach7.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/images/beach8.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/images/beach9.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
</div>`
```

the class='slide' divs slpit the scrollable content...

the only thing missing is the appropriate css to define the sliding area anc navigation links

```
`#nav { margin: 20px auto }
#nav a { padding: 4px 6px; margin: 3px; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; background-color: #ddd }
#nav a.activeSlide { color: #c00 }
#nav a:focus { outline: none; }

.slideshow { margin: 20px auto; padding: 0; clear: left; }
.slide { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
.slideshow, .slide { height: 232px; width: 710px; }`
```

it worked for me like a charm.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer and add the code from the other site into here? If that link breaks or changes, your answer will be rendered useless.